# ArgumentError: Error #2025 fix when removeChild

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I'm trying to make a spaceship game and I'm having a problem when I'm using the `removeChild()` method to remove the projectiles or the enemy ships out of the stage.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
var bulletsArr:Array = new Array();
var eShipsArr:Array = new Array();


for (var c = 0; c < eShipsArr.length; c++){
stage.addChild(eShipsArr[c]);
}
....

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,shoot);

function shoot (e:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(e.keyCode==17){
    var pj:projectile = new projectile();
    pj.x = SShip.x;
    pj.y = SShip.y;
    stage.addChild(pj);
    bulletsArr.push(pj);
    if(bulletsArr.length >= 10){
       bulletsArr = bulletsArr.slice(1,10);
    }
}
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkHit);

function checkHit (e:Event):void{
for (var d = 0; d < bulletsArr.length; d++){
    for(var f = 0; f < eShipsArr.length; f++){
        if(bulletsArr[d].hitTestObject(eShipsArr[f])){
            trace(bulletsArr[d].parent);
            stage.removeChild(bulletsArr[d]); //ArgumentError: Error #2025!!!!
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I use `removeChild()` with `stage`, the trace returns `null`. Without it the trace returns `Stage object`. In both cases the same error jumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you are trying to remove a child that was already removed?

You are not removing it from the array, so the next loop or the next `checkHit` call will include checks on objects that were possibly already removed from stage. A `hitTestObject` check would return `true` even with objects that are not on the stage.

Untested (note that the bulletes array is being iterated backwards to avoid problems with the length when removing array elements):

```
for (var d = bulletsArr.length - 1; d >= 0; d--){
    for(var f = 0; f < eShipsArr.length; f++){
        if(bulletsArr[d].hitTestObject(eShipsArr[f])){
            trace(bulletsArr[d].parent);
            stage.removeChild(bulletsArr[d]); 
            bulletsArr.splice(d, 1); // remove bullet from array
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here's some untested (properly typed) code in case it is possible that a single bullet can collide with two or more ships, and all you need to do is remove the bullets:

```
for(var f:Number = 0; f < eShipsArr.length; f ++)
{
    for(var d:Number = bulletsArr.length - 1; d >= 0; d --)
    {
        if(bulletsArr[d].hitTestObject(eShipsArr[f]))
        {
            stage.removeChild(bulletsArr[d]);
            bulletsArr.splice(d, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The loops where interchanged, that way removed bullets are not checked again.

In case it is possible that a single bullet can collide with two or more ships, and you are planning to do something with ships that collided with the bullet too, then try this:

```
    for(var d:Number = bulletsArr.length - 1; d >= 0; d --)
    {
        var bullet:DisplayObject = bulletsArr[d];
        var bulletHitSomething:Boolean = false;

        for(var f:Number = 0; f < eShipsArr.length; f ++)
        {
            if(bullet.hitTestObject(eShipsArr[f]))
            {
                if(!bulletHitSomething)
                {
                    bulletHitSomething = true;
                    stage.removeChild(bullet);
                    bulletsArr.splice(d, 1);
                }
                // do other, ship specific stuff here
            }
        }
    }
```

The current bullet object reference is stored in a variable, and all the checks are done against that variable instead of the element in the array using array access. Unlike the array access method where it coule possibly access a non existent index, this way possible consecutive checks on the same bullet should be fine. Also a variable stores whether the bullet already hit something, so that it doesn't try to remove that bullet again.

Comment: i get "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties." why does it happend?

Comment: You'll at least need to tell where exactly the error occours, and a short hint of what's going on when it happens would be helpful too. Is it possible in your game that a single bullet collides white two or more ships?

Comment: Please check if the additional example in my answer fixes the problem.

Comment: there are some ships on the same collom but it happens with one ship as well the error comes from the for loop that was changed but it happens with or without the fix

Comment: Well, the error indicates that you are trying to access a property of an undefined object. It would be good to use a proper debugging environmentso  that you'll get a detailed stack trace with line numbers when an error occours. Without knowing where exactly it happens, it's pretty hard to tell what could possibly be wrong. I've updated my answer with some modified code, maybe that'll help, however, if not, please try to elaborate where exactly the error occours!

Comment: it works! tnx youre a genius! thank you so much for the trouble :)